# Git repository inside Xcode local folder

Tags: xcode, git, xcode5

I'm working on some classes that can be reused in other projects. I will add the first release to github when I'm done. The project does nothing, just the classes are useful. I don't want to commit the whole Xcode project. I just want to commit the classes I'm working with, because that's what the people will copy in their projects. 
If I push the whole project, I have to ask the users of the classes to dig into the project and copy the classes manually, deleting the rest. It's dirty.

So I came up with a solution.

1. I created a plain cocoa project.
2. Inside the project I created in command line a folder, let's say MyClasses
3. I added the classes files in that folder.
4. I added that folder to the Xcode project by reference, not copying.
5. Then in command line I made a git init inside that folder, added all the files and I made the first commit.

So far so good. I'm working with the interface provided by Xcode to manage the repository and it understands that the git repository it's located only in that folder.

My questions are, will this crash in the future? 
Is Xcode prepared to work in this way?
I wonder if somebody already did this before. In this way I can dedicate the repository only to the classes and exclude all the files related with Xcode, nibs, plists and so forth.

This extends the question to: Is it possible to have multiple repositories inside the same Xcode project? I didn't try that yet.

Comment: Might help to distinguish between a project and a workspace.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want to distribute some specific Objective-C source files using git, but also include them in your own local Xcode project to work on within Xcode.

If that's the case, then do exactly as you’ve described. In other words:

1. Store all of the source files (that you want to distribute) inside a single directory
2. Initialise a git repo inside that directory
3. Add that directory to your local Xcode project, making sure that the appropriate source files are added to your build targets.

You can add as many individual repositories as you like this way.

> will this crash in the future?

No, the configuration shouldn't cause any crashes.

There is one caveat to this approach, *if* you have collaborators. Since you aren't sharing your *.xcodeproj files, your build settings and file references won’t be updated when someone else modifies the file structure or adds or remove files. You'll probably find yourself having to manually update file references in your local project every time you pull from the remote, otherwise you may run into build errors.

> Is Xcode prepared to work in this way?

From my experience, yes, it works fine. If you tend to use the Xcode interface to manage git though, just be aware that Xcode only recognises files under source control for the repos that it has "checked out". Based on what I've seen, Xcode will do this automatically for any repos that it finds in the current project directory, or in any folder or group reference.

Additionally, it gets a bit problematic if a file belongs to two or more repos at once; Xcode will only interact with one of them and I don't know if there is any way to choose which. This should be easy to avoid if you don't nest your repositories.

In Xcode 5 you can see which git repos are checked out under "Working Copies" in the "Source Control" menu. Xcode can also tell you which repo each file belongs to, under "Source Control" in the File inspector.

> Is it possible to have multiple repositories inside the same Xcode project?

Yes. You can have multiple repositories living side-by-side under your Xcode project directory, just like you can anywhere else. In fact, you could just as easily put your repos elsewhere on your filesystem and add them to your project via reference; you don’t have to store all of your git repos/source files in that directory for this to work.

Hope that helps.